# htmlunit-2.7 - java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

Tags: java, soapui, htmlunit

I am trying to use htmlunit-2.7 Library (which is the default library avalilable in SoapUI-5.2.1) to Automate the User Level Token Retrieval Process (Authorization Code Grant flow of OAuth2).
But I am receiving the Connection reset error when I tried to connect to Google Page via WebClient Class of htmlunit-2.7.

Below is my code,

Dependency Jar Files I have used in my project,

***commons-codec-1.3.jar
commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
commons-io-2.4.jar
commons-lang-2.4.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
htmlunit-2.7.jar
htmlunit-core-js-2.7.jar
sac-1.3.jar
xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar***

```
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlForm;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlSubmitInput;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlTextInput;

public class HTMLUnitClass 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        System.out.println("Starting the  Script");

        try
         {
          //Webpage Login  
            WebClient driver = new WebClient();
            System.out.println("Instantiating the WebClient");


            driver.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            System.out.println("Enabling the Java Script");
            driver.setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
            System.out.println("Disabling the Throw Exception on Script Error");


            try
            {
                driver.getPage("https://www.google.com");
                System.out.println("Getting the Google Page");

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("Exception in the HTML Unit Driver Block: " + e);
            }


            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("Exception in the HTTPClient Block" + e);
            }




    }

}
```

And I am getting the below error - stack below,

```
Starting the Script
Instantiating the HTMLUnit Driver
Enabling the Java Script
Disabling the Throw Exception on Script Error
Jul 18, 2017 6:34:41 PM org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Connection reset
Jul 18, 2017 6:34:41 PM org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry
INFO: Retrying request
Jul 18, 2017 6:34:41 PM org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Connection reset
Jul 18, 2017 6:34:41 PM org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry
INFO: Retrying request
Jul 18, 2017 6:34:41 PM org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Connection reset
Jul 18, 2017 6:34:41 PM org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry
INFO: Retrying request
Exception in the HTML Unit Driver Block: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

> NOTE-1:
>   Please note that, I cannot go with the latest HtmlUnitDriver Library
>   (Jar), because that will cause version conflicts with the default
>   libraries of the SoapUI-5.2.1 That is the reason for me to stick to
>   the Default Libraries provided in the Installation package of
>   SoapUI-5.2.1 and trying to integrate this solution with the Groovy
>   Script available in one of the Test Steps of the SoapUI.
>
> NOTE-2: I tried using the Apache OAuth Client 2.0 Library as well for
>   automating the Level Token Generation ([My Clarification on OAuth
>   Client 2.0 Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44974292/issues-with-generating-authorization-code-and-user-token-using-apache-oauth-clie))

**Could someone throw some lights on how to resolve this Connection RESET issue ?**

Comment: Found this on an old post. Try adding it in webClient.getOptions().setSSLClientProtocols(new String[] { "TLSv1.2",
"TLSv1.1" }); . Taken from here https://sourceforge.net/p/htmlunit/mailman/message/34726040/

Comment: I tried with `2.7`, and your case works.  Which country are you from? Since `google.com` can go to e.g. `google.de`. Also, which Java/eclipse/maven version you use?

Comment: @AhmedAshour: I am from India but am using the network from US (VM).
Below are the version details that you've asked..
Java: Build 1.8.0_131-b11
Eclipse: Version: Neon Release (4.6.0) & Build id: 20160613-1800

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem my self and the correct solution is the one proposed on the first comment by @canpan14

My solution to overcome this error is the following:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BEST_SUPPORTED);
webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true); //ignore insecure ssl exception
webClient.getOptions().setSSLClientProtocols(new String[] { "TLSv1.2","TLSv1.1" });
```

The last line of code actually sets the type of TLS to use. The preferred is TLSv1.2 for your code to work correctly.